# Every Orbit of ODE are either the same or disjoints : so in $\mathbb R$ there is only one orbit?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y'(t)=y(t)$. So the orbit is $\mathcal O(y_0)=\{y(t)\mid y(0)=y_0, t\in I\}$. It's written in my course that all orbits are either disjoints or coincides. But in $\mathbb R$, don't we have only one orbit ? i.e. if $x_0\neq y_0$, we must have $\mathcal O(x_0)=\mathcal O(y_0)$, no ? Since the orbits is necessary included in $[0,\infty )$, no ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $y'(t)=y(t)$ we have

$$\mathcal O(y_0)=\{y_0e^t: t \in I\}.$$

Can you take it from here ?

Comment: but this is equal to $[0,\infty )$ (if $I=\mathbb R$). So it confirm the fact that there is only one orbit... does it ?

Comment: No, if $y_0<0$, then ..... ??

Comment: ok, so there are 2 orbits... $[0,\infty )$ and $(-\infty ,0]$

Comment: @user659895: No, three orbits, since $\{ 0 \}$ is an orbit of its own.